# Schedule Power BI dashboard refreshing on Azure

Tags: azure, cloud, powerbi, scheduling, business-intelligence

I have a SQL Database in Azure and I connect Power BI reports with it. Now I want to refresh my Power BI dashboards automatically. I heard we can do it on Azure, but unable to find any documentation on it.

Have anyone done this before?

Please, share some documentation that I can use to do this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make sure that the dataset in the report is updated. If you are using Direct Query, it will connect to your database directly and no refreshing is needed. However, if the data is imported, you need to [schedule a refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-scheduled-refresh) for this dataset. For Pro accounts, you can schedule up to 8 refreshes per 24 hours, or up to 48 for Premium.

Then when you pin tiles to a dash board, this dashboard will be updated automatically (refreshed every 15 minutes).

You can find more details in [Data refresh in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-data) article.